# Unable to install TCP/IP Printer in Windows

Tags: windows, printing, printer

I have a home network with an HP Laserjet 4000 on it, accessed via a Jetdirect 600n card.  The printer works fine on other machines (including those running Windows 7x64).  The network address (192.168.2.211) is accessible from the laptop via a browser without issue.

I cannot install the printer onto my laptop.  When I try to install it via the "Add Printer Wizard", the wizard detects the printer type and the IP address without issue.  When I click "Next", i get the error "Cannot Load Wizard Pages for standard TCP/IP Port".

If I install the printer first as a local (LPT-based) printer, and then try to add the TCP/IP port, I cannot do this - when I click "Add port" in the properties page, I get a list of "Printer ports", which does not have Standard TCP/IP port as an option.

What I have already tried:
Creating the registry entries to re-enable the "Standard TCP/IP Port" option, as seen on this site - i.e. the following:
"HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Contro l\Print\Monitor\
Add key
Standard TCP/IP Port
Add String Value; value name=Driver; value data=tcpmon.dll
under Standard TCP/IP Port
Add Key
Ports
Add three Dwords in Ports
LprAckTimeout value data= 180
StatusUpda****abled value data= 1
StatusUpdateInterval value data= 10
stop and start spooler
This hasn't worked;  I also exported that registry tree from another Windows 7x64 machine which does work, and imported that.  Still not working.

Checked on the files that are used for TCP/IP Ports and they are all there:
in \windows\system32
tcpmon.dll
tcpmib.dll
tcpmonui.dll
I don't have any of the files that have been references in the %systemroot% folder that would cause conflicts:
Wsnmp32.dll, Ntprint.dll, Tcpmib.dll, Mgmtapi.dll, or Snmpapi.dll

Run sfc/ scannow - this apparently found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them.  The CBS.log file is unreadable, oddly.

In short, I'm out of ideas.  It's not often that I can't find a solution for a computer problem, and I have done a lot of looking - all of it has pointed to the solutions above which haven't worked.  Judging by the searches I've seen, I'm not the only one.  Help would be appreciated.

Comment: "Run sfc/ scannow - this apparently found corrupt files but was unable to fix some of them." Fix your repository until SFC finishes without error. Otherwise we have to assume its probably due to a corrupted system file that you haven't fixed via SFC yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed the issue by removing the drivers and printer values under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Print\Environments\Windows x64\Print Processors
```

older and installed printers/drivers that can't be used by Windows 10 kept causing the printer sub system to crash and not work.